# Changing the icon of an .exe file in Rust

Tags: rust, icons, exe, rs.exe

So I did some research and found out about rs.exe in Windows to convert my resources.rs file containing a name to_do and PATH to ico to res. The only problem is after navigating to its directory and running the command rs resource.exe. I get the error RC1109 which im told is that the rc.exe can not find the path.

What am I doing wrong? should I keep my resources.rs file in the same folder as the rc.exe?

do I have to format the text included in the file in some sort of way?

As always thanks for your help!

Comment: You mention rc.exe, but have tagged rs.exe? Overall, are you asking how you can add an icon to your exe, build from `cargo build`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`winres`](https://crates.io/crates/winres) crate to set an icon for the .exe when you run `cargo build` or `cargo run`.

Add this to your **Cargo.toml**:

```
[package]
...
build = "build.rs"

[build-dependencies]
winres = "0.1"
```

Then create a **build.rs** file in the same directory where the *Cargo.toml* is located, with the following content:

```rust
extern crate winres;

fn main() {
  if cfg!(target_os = "windows") {
    let mut res = winres::WindowsResource::new();
    res.set_icon("my_icon.ico"); // Replace this with the filename of your .ico file.
    res.compile().unwrap();
  }
}
```

Then you have to copy your .ico file in that same directory, too. Don't forget to change the filename in *build.rs*.

Comment: You can try to delete the /target directory and rebuild again. Or try to copy the exe to another location. Sometimes the file explorer caches these icons...

Comment: Yes I got it to work, thank you man, I don't know if it helped but I added the build.rs to my package in the cargo.toml

Comment: Yes, sorry. Forgot to write this down. Answer is updated.